# creating a table with fixed header and dynamic values on angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to create a kind of skill map, where i have a fixed header with 2 columns and dynamic data to map on it.

What I'm trying to figure out is a way to show the `[experienceTime]` based on the header name.

This is the goal:

[image: sample]

There is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skillmap-sample-m9buyi) with all I achieved util now.

I tried to use the javascript way with `getElementById` and `setAttribute`, but `getElementById` always returns me null.

(Not sure if its a angular limitation or its because I'm loading all the data asynchronously).

I also read about `@ViewChildren` but hasn't found solid information on how to use it dynamically.

So any advice on how should I do this is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried primeng table. here is link if you wanna try https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/scroll

Comment: I checked their samples, this one:(https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/colgroup) to be more specific and its probably possible but ill need to build a new array with all my data.
If i not get another way to do it without need to build a new array with everything, this is a good option.
*Edit
There is a sample of my data inside the stackblitz i provided, i'll edit the post later to make it more clear.